# Using local storage or cookie to detect a menu click

Tags: javascript

I need to set a cookie or use local storage if the customer clicked on the megaMenu. This needs to be false by default and the set to true on the next page if the customer clicked on a menu button. Any help would be appreciated. The following is what I have so far, but I'm stuck on how to get megaClicked = true on the second page.

```
var megaClicked = { value: false };
var megaMenu = $("#menu-top-navigation > div");
// check local storage on page load
if (localStorage.getItem('mega')) {
    megaClicked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mega'))
}

megaMenu.bind('click', function () {
    megaClicked.value = true;
    localStorage.setItem('mega', JSON.stringify(megaClicked));
})
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: sorry i just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This get the value if mega exist and store it if not.

```
var megaMenu = $("#menu-top-navigation > div");
// check local storage on page load
if (localStorage.getItem('mega')) {
  var megaClicked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mega'))
}else{
  var megaClicked = { value: false };
  localStorage.setItem('mega', JSON.stringify(megaClicked));

 }

megaMenu.bind('click', function () {
    megaClicked.value = true;
    localStorage.setItem('mega', JSON.stringify(megaClicked));
})
```

Keep in mind once you run the code the local storage item `"mega"` will remain until you remove it. So first `if` will always be true. Maybe a shorter version could be something like:

```
if (+localStorage.getItem('mega')) {
  var megaClicked = +localStorage.getItem('mega');
}else{
  localStorage.setItem('mega', 0);

 }

$("#menu-top-navigation > div").bind('click', function () {    
    localStorage.setItem('mega', 1);
})
```

Comment: any thoughts how I can make the code better? @emeeus

Answer (score 0):

The following Demo does not function here on SO. To test a functioning demo, go to this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNcTw52u2OBFI40oO7FS?p=preview). It features 2 pages:

- Since the pages are in the same domain, both pages share the same WebStorage. Having both pages share the same external script will apply the same behavior to the same WebStorage consistently.
- The function `menuUse(temp)` passes a Boolean assigned as `temp`. If you want to remove the "used" flag after it has been detected, pass `temp` as `"used"`:

  ```
  menuUse(true)
  ```

If you want this behavior without having to use the `temp` parameter, change all objects called: `localStorage` to `sessionStorage`.

**Details commented in Demo and [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNcTw52u2OBFI40oO7FS?p=preview). Demo does not function, see [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNcTw52u2OBFI40oO7FS?p=preview) instead.**

## [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNcTw52u2OBFI40oO7FS?p=preview)

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  // Pass true if you want to remove flag from storage after it's been detected
  menuUse();

  $('#mega').on('click', showHide);

  // Anytime the megamenu is used the "used" flag is stored as true
  function showHide(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    localStorage.setItem("used", JSON.stringify("used"));
  }

  // On every page load of either page1 or page 2, there will be a check for the "used" flag
  function menuUse(temp = false) {
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("used"));
    if (data === "used") {
      return action(temp);
    } else if (data === null) {
      console.log('Mega NOT used.');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('Flag does NOT exist yet.');
      return false;
    }
  }

  // If menuUse passed through true and the "used" flag is true, then the flag will be removed
  function action(temp) {
    if (temp) {
      console.log('Mega used, webStorage entry renoved.');
      localStorage.removeItem("used");
    } else {
      console.log("Mega used.");
    }
    return false;
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="lib/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>PAGE 1</h1>
  <a href='page2.html'>PAGE 2</a>
  <nav id="mega">
    <a href='#/'>MEGA</a>
    <ul class="hide">
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#/">ITEM</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <!--Both pages share the same external script-->
  <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```